# Javascript combobox with typeahead and hierarchical items

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I want to create a combobox with a hierarchical list of items. I need to be able to select the parent items as well as the children individually. I also need to be able to provide typeahead capabilities for this combobox.

For example, I want to make a combobox with this data in JS:

Canada

--Ontario

--Quebec

USA

--Massachusetts

--Ohio

--Texas

From this dropdown I want to be able to select any of the provinces/states individually. I also want to be able to select "Canada" without selecting it's children.

I've tried Select2 and have been digging around JQuery UI to see if it is possible, but so far I can't quite achieve the behaviour I need. I'm writing this page using bootstrap, but the given typeahead in boostrap doesn't seem to work with comboboxes at all (that I can see).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Chosen javascript plugin to achieve this.
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: That would work...except I need to be able to select the opt-group headers, not just their children. I don't see a way of doing that with Chosen.

Comment: That looks like a pretty slick plugin. Might have to give that a whirl on my next project!

Answer (score 0):

You can store custom JS objects for each typeahead result so that it can displays and store more than just a string (a type, or ID for example). Using that would let you have different logic for country vs province/state. Here's an example of doing so:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/3682

So in the updater function, you could have logic based on your custom object to determine whether it's a parent or child that was clicked.

As far as making the parent look different than the child, I haven't used it myself, but there is a templating system in bootstrap. Check out this link for an example:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2441

You could likely use this to differentiate the parent and child look and feel.

Comment: @webda2l Updated. Bootstrap was moved to a new Github account.